# Условия с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать регулярные выражения для поиска ссылок при этом отделять ссылки в тегах.

К примеру есть какой-то текст, в котором есть ссылки:

```
Текст текст текст https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ текст текст <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">https://ru.stackoverflow.com/</a> текст https://site.com текст
```

Мне нужно найти все ссылки, которые не упакованы в тег <a></a> и упаковать, а ссылку `https://site.com` вовсе удалить из текста... как правильно это сделать не понимаю, и возможно ли это вообще сделать в одной регулярке?

Comment: а зачем это делать в одной регулярке? Отдельно находите ссылки и оборачиваете, отдельно удаляете конкретный сайт. Ищите ссылку начиная с `https:` до чего-нить пробельного и заворачивайте

Comment: Так хорошо ссылки я нашел к примеру нашёл и обернул их в тег <a> ... так при этом у меня оборачиваются и те ссылки которые уже находятся в теге <a>

Comment: [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926142/regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link) с англоязычного SO подойдёт для начала? Можете его видоизменить, и находить ссылки без <a>.

Comment: А разве регулярки на C# и на php не отличаются друг от друга?

Comment: Немного отличаются, да, но можете найти аналогичные посты именно для PHP, типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001328/php-regex-to-get-string-inside-href-tag).

Comment: негативный просмотр назад на `href=['"]` решит вопрос с тем что уже обернуты